# What registration is required for 250g to 2kg drones in Australia?

Tags: regulations, fixed-wing, license, sub-2-kilograms, australia

As some of you might know already, I'm planning to get into model aviation. I've been looking at the [CASA rules](https://www.casa.gov.au/drones/rules/) and trying to get my head around them. So far, I've built a [FliteTest Tiny Trainer](https://store.flitetest.com/flite-test-mighty-mini-tiny-trainer-speed-build-electric-airplane-kit-940mm-flt-1071/p1175441) with no electronics (it's just the foam airframe). Before I buy and fit the electronics for it, I want to know what registration I will have to do (if any). It looks like it will be in the `very small` category (250g-2kg) with battery and electronics. I'd just be flying it line-of-sight for recreation. I probably wouldn't be flying it exclusively at CASA-approved model airfields.

I've probably forgotten to write some information in there; if you need any just ask in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](https://www.casa.gov.au/drones/register) you don't need to register your drone "you’re only flying for sport or recreation, including model aircraft flown at CASA-approved model airfields". Since you're only intending to fly your drone in recreational purposes it seems like you don't need to register your drone even if it weighs over 250 grams.

I am no legal expert though, and if I were you I would contact CASA and ask for clarification if you are want to be absolutely certain about how you should do.

Comment: Based on most CASA pages, I would agree, except for one that states: `If you’re only flying your home built drone for sport or recreation, you do not need to register it until March 2022.`
What do you make of this?